# Is it possible to set captions for each image when initializing a gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

Using [magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html), is it possible to set captions for each image when initializing a gallery via javascript? There isn't a DOM element for each image, so it's not possible to use the title attribute (or any other attribute) as a pointer to the caption.

```
$('#my-gallery').magnificPopup({
    items: [
        {
            src: 'image.jpg',
            title: 'Some Title'
        },
        {
            src: 'image2.jpg',
            title: 'Some Other Title'
        }
    ],
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    },
    type: 'image'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the following parameters to add a caption to your image as per magnific popup documentation (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#image-type):

```
$('#my-gallery').magnificPopup({
    items: [
        {
            src: 'image.jpg',
            title: 'Some Title'
        },
        {
            src: 'image2.jpg',
            title: 'Some Other Title'
        }
    ],
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    },
    type: 'image',
    image: {
       markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
            '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
            '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
            '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
              '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
              '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
            '</div>'+
          '</div>', // Popup HTML markup. `.mfp-img` div will be replaced with img tag, `.mfp-close` by close button

         tError: '<a href="%url%">The image</a> could not be loaded.' // Error message
   }
});
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wmboxLfr/3/

Note the key thing here is that the image mark up has 'mfp-title', and the items passes title as parameter. Cheers!

Comment: I have updated my answer, would that work as a solution?

Comment: Thank you for making a fiddle but my question refers to intialising a gallery, as opposed to a single image

Comment: Okay, now its working as a gallery, with the parameters you provided merged with the image option.

Comment: Thanks Arathi! Works great